# Can we use multiple when then condition in a single rule in Drools.?

Tags: java, jboss, drools

I am writing a .drl file to implement Drools rules. As per business requirements I need to check 3 conditions for a single rule. So my question is, is it possible to have multiple `when` in the same rule.

I did search for many hours, but I didn't get any useful info. Can someone please guide me how to write multiple `when` in the single rule in drools.

Ie is it possible to do like this?

```
rule "Test rule 1"
    when 
        condition1
    then
        <execute code>
    when
        condition2
    then
        <execute code>
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, 80% sure you can not. You caught me with a opened .drl and did a try, says 'mismatched input', but fails on the inmediate token after the second `then`. Hence the 80% (to say some number). Cheerfully the compiler passed all along the second `when` without fail.

Try and post.

Comment: correct i tried multiple it says "mismatched input" :(

so if i want to use 4 condition the i have to make 4 new rules right ?

Comment: If I think about the `when-then-when-then` scheme as you do, guess you can do at least two things: split to two rules and salience difference, or an `if-'then'` construct inside the `then`.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Basically, you will need to implement two rules, each one with one of the `when` blocks. The result should be exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

No We cannot do it. I also tried to implement the same , but eventually end up writing multiple rules to fulfil all when/then conditions, something like below

rule "RULE DESC"
when
CONDITION
then
EXECUTION
end

rule "RULE DESC"
when
CONDITION
then
EXECUTION
end

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30959925)